# How to create Alert confrim Yes/No with MvcHtmlString in MVC C#

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-mvc, alert, mvchtmlstring

The following code displays a warninng via MvcHtmlString.

**in C#**

```
public static MvcHtmlString ShowAlert(this HtmlHelper helper, string message)
{
     StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

     sb.Append(@"$.confirm({" +
                      "title: false," +
                      "content: '" + message + "'," +
                      "type: 'dark'," +
                      "boxWidth: '45%'," +
                      "animation: 'RotateY',closeAnimation: 'RotateY',rtl: true," +
                      "typeAnimated: true," +
                      "buttons:" +
                      "{Close: {" +
                      "btnClass: 'btn-blue'} }});");

     return MvcHtmlString.Create(sb.ToString());
}
```

**in Script**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        $('#bSubmit').click(event,
            function() {
                event.preventDefault();
                @Html.ShowAlert("Test");
            });
</script>
```

[image]

I want to display an Alert in **MvcHtmlString** which is `Yes/No` and returns the clicked buttons so **I can use the value in the script.**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could create a javascript library of common functions in your application and include the confirm dialog into it. This way you could use the return value of the confirm dialog in the script as a callback.

site.js:

```
function showConfirm(message, clickCallback) {
    $.confirm({
        title: false,
        content: message,
        type: 'dark',
        boxWidth: '45%',
        animation: 'RotateY',
        closeAnimation: 'RotateY', 
        rtl: true,
        typeAnimated: true,
        buttons: { 
            Close: function () {
                clickCallback("Close");
            }
        } 
    });
}
```

Names of the buttons could be put into the function as another parameter, for example:

```
function showConfirmWithMultipleButtons(message, buttons /* array of names */, clickCallback)
```

Usage:

```
showConfirm('Simple confirm message', function(buttonName) {
    $.alert(buttonName);
});
```

Comment: I want to convert this Alert to Yes / No in MvcHtmlString, you understand what I mean.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to use alertify [https://alertifyjs.com/](https://alertifyjs.com/confirm.html), it has it's own functions to create what you are asking, it would easy to use, you'll just need to write a new MvcHtmlString  that writes this:

```
alertify.confirm('Confirm Title', 'Confirm Message', function(){ alertify.success('Ok') }
                , function(){ alertify.error('Cancel')});
```

you can find examples and documentation on the given link

Comment: I want to convert this Alert to Yes / No in MvcHtmlString, you understand what I mean.